# Xamarin Forms Prism Naming convention with subfolders

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Is there a standered naming convention when making folders in a prism project ?

This works
**ViewModals:**

```
HelloWorldPageViewModel
```

**View:**

```
HelloWorldPage
```

**App:**

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Views.HelloWorldPage >();
```

***But for some reason , this does not work***

I added the folling folders Login > Template >

**ViewModals:**

```
Login.Template.HelloWorldPageViewModel
```

**View:**

```
Login.Template.HelloWorldPage
```

**App:**

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Views.Login.Template.HelloWorldPage >();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Change the naming conventions using the `ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver`. You can see an example in this blog post: http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/
2. Or you can simply register your VM directly with `ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<View, ViewModel>();`
3. If you are using Xamarin.Forms simply provide the VM in the `Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<View, ViewModel>();` method

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge Prism checks namepaces of ViewModels and Views.

So if your have a view it has to be under Views.Something , and if you want to have a viewmodel for it should be "ViewModels.SomethingViewModel"